# How can I use fopen() and fread() to substitute imread() within MATLAB?

Tags: c, matlab, fopen, fread, imread

I want to replace `imread` with `fopen` and `fread` so that I can create C code from my *MATLAB* file.

While using the MATLAB coder utility, `imread` cannot be used (since it is an extrinsic function). Therefore I am looking to substitute `imread1 which is currently reading *.JPG*s with the combination of`fopen`and`fread`. My assertions at the start of the program are:

```
assert(isa(IM, 'uint8'));
assert(size(IM, 1) < 100);
assert(size(IM, 2) < 100);
assert(size(IM, 3) == 3);
```

Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hey! Can you please add to your question what you've tried and your results?

Comment: What image file format will you be using? [`fread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) will read the file one byte at a time. You'll need to know how those bytes correspond to the image structure.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect these comments

Comment: The way I see it, you are better off interfacing with an already implemented jpeg decoder (via Matlab Mex, maybe use libjpeg) than actually rolling your own JPEG decoder to get pixel data into a matrix (data is stored using Discrete Cosine Transforms or WH Transforms rather than directly as colour per pixel). If you still want to do that, you will want to look at the JPEG Standard or look at an [open source implementation](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @RollenD'Souza This should be the answer. If you put it up, I'll choose it to be the correct answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rollen D'Souza has commented on the question - using `coder.ceval` and an implemented JPEG decoder would be the best option here.